# i can not make span editable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am uploading images with span text dynamically using javascript. It's uploading with span text perfectly but i am trying make that span editable using jquery code,

```
$('span').bind('dblclick',
  function(){
  $(this).attr('contentEditable',true);
  });
```

After uploading some images with span, making alignment using **jquery gridly plugin**.That code i m using,

```
$('.gridly').gridly({
   columns: 8
   // base: 60, // px 
   //gutter: 20 // px
   });
  $('.gridly').gridly('draggable');

        });
```

Here is my demo what i tired : http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/72cr4bvk/8/

I hope someone will correct my code and tell me why i can not edit span?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('span').bind('dblclick', function() {
        $(this).attr('contentEditable', true);
    }).blur(
        function() {
            $(this).attr('contentEditable', false);
        });
```

and here is the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Q4WLJ/1/)

Comment: I updated your code but not working! check this http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/72cr4bvk/9/

Comment: This one works, http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Q4WLJ/ for some reason the first double click is not working, but after the first double click if you double click again you can edit the text!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65416/discussion-between-manivasagam-and-ehsan).